# Using library that only extends Array object

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I have a library that has type definitions like this:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        addRange<T>(elements: T[]): void;
        aggregate<U>(accumulator: (accum: U, value?: T, index?: number, list?: T[]) => any, initialValue?: U): any;
    }
}
```

This library is then exported to a NPM package, but how do I consume it in another project?

If I try doing:

```
['a', 'b'].addRange(['c', 'd']);
```

I get

```
Property 'addRange' does not exist on type
```

But I can't just import `addRange` because they are Array extensions.

How do I import this library so Typescript knows about it?

Comment: Can you share your `tsconfig.json`?  are you using webpack or some other packaging technology?

Comment: @Amy you mean from the library or the project that consumes the library?

Comment: Your project which uses the library.  My question pertains to your built tools.

Comment: That project is actually an Angular project, I haven't made any changes yet to it, except for just doing npm install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally expose the types in `package.json` `types` field of the npm package.
If these types include global type augmentations, they will be automatically picked up  by the compiler, as soon as you require the package in the client project.

package.json (library):

```
{
  "name": "__testPackage",
  "types": "index.d.ts"
  ...
}
```

index.d.ts (library):

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    addRange<T>(elements: T[]): void;
    aggregate<U>(
      accumulator: (accum: U, value?: T, index?: number, list?: T[]) => any,
      initialValue?: U
    ): any;
  }
}

export const foo: number;
```

app.ts (client):

```
// if you remove the import, Array.prototype.addRange won't compile
import { foo } from "__testPackage";

console.log(foo); // 42

const arr = ["a", "b"];
arr.addRange(["c", "d"]); // compiles
console.log(arr); // [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
```

Comment: Ok thanks, this is the way I went with: `export const init = () => null;`, then I can do `import { init } from 'lib';` in the `app.component.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

create a annonimous function that will add the extra features to the array and enclose it to () so you can call it.

example:

```
(function(){
   // add the extension methods here
})()
```

Then add it to the tsconfig.json or tsconfig.app.json in Angular 8 to the files

```
{
  ...
  "files": [
    // your extension path here,
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  ...
}
```